# Where is the best place to download FlashAudioPlugin.swf when using SoundJS?

Tags: soundjs

The file is required to use the Flash player in SoundJS (see [here](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/blob/9f2350820228e9b605dad669506fdad2f83b3fbc/src/soundjs/flashaudio/FlashAudioPlugin.js#L181)), but is not included in any of their [downloadable builds](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/releases).

Answer (score 0):

The latest file is in the zipped source code, in  src\soundjs\flashaudio\FlashAudioPlugin.swf. You can also get the latest version [here](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/raw/master/src/soundjs/flashaudio/FlashAudioPlugin.swf).

Answer (score 0):

FlashAudioPlugin content is considered an extra and is not included in the cdn builds, but you can find versioned builds on the [github repo](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS) in the [lib folder](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/tree/master/lib).  The swf file can be found in the [src/soundjs/flashaudio](https://github.com/CreateJS/SoundJS/tree/master/src/soundjs/flashaudio) folder.

If you need older copies of the swf, then can be found in the releases on github.

Hope that helps.